# MongoDB : create a view which is the union of several collections

Tags: mongodb

I currently have a collection that i need to split in several smaller collections. Is there a way to make a View containing the union of all my smaller collections ?

According to the [MongoDB Manual](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createView/#db.createView), i could use the **$lookup** operator in the pipeline, but it ends up being more like a "join" than an "union".

Here is an example of what i want to do :

**Current collection :**

```
{ _id: 1, name: "abc", country: "us" }
{ _id: 2, name: "def", country: "us" }
{ _id: 3, name: "123", country: "de" }
{ _id: 4, name: "456", country: "de" }
```

Splitting into :

**Collection_US**

```
{ _id: 1, name: "abc", country: "us" }
{ _id: 2, name: "def", country: "us" }
```

**Collection_DE**

```
{ _id: 3, name: "123", country: "de" }
{ _id: 4, name: "456", country: "de" }
```

And then, make a view :

**View**

```
{ _id: 1, name: "abc", country: "us" }
{ _id: 2, name: "def", country: "us" }
{ _id: 3, name: "123", country: "de" }
{ _id: 4, name: "456", country: "de" }
```

Is it possible to do this ?

Comment: I think you will need to manage that at the application level. Which programming language you are using here?

Comment: The application is written in PHP with ZF2. However, the collection is quite big. There is currently 70 millions documents in it and it grows by 1 million every 2 days. That's why i would like to avoid managing this at application level if possible.

Answer (score 2):

This is the same modified of taminov's code.

```
db.createView('union_view', 'us', [
  {
    $facet: {
      us: [
        {$match: {}}
      ],
      de: [
        {$limit: 1},
        {
          $lookup: {
            from: 'de',
            localField: '__unexistingfield',
            foreignField: '__unexistingfield',
            as: '__col2'
          }
        },
        {$unwind: '$__col2'},
        {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: '$__col2'}}
      ]
    },
  },
  {$project: {data: {$concatArrays: ['$us', '$de']}}},
  {$unwind: '$data'},
  {$replaceRoot: {newRoot: '$data'}}
])
```

Answer (score 0):

its very hacky but will work for small collections. you may end up having to use a real collection if the collections are big.

```
db.createView('union_view', 'col1', [
{
    $facet: {
        col1: [
            { $match:{}}
        ],
        col2: [
            { $limit:1},
            { $lookup:{
                from: 'col2',
                localField: '__unexistingfield',
                foreignField: '__unexistingfield',
                as: '__col2'
            }},
            { $unwind:'$__col2'},
            { $replaceRoot: {newRoot: '$__col2'}}
        ]  
    },
},
{ $project: { filesFolders: {$setUnion: ['$files', '$folders']}}},
{ $unwind: '$filesFolders' },
{ $replaceRoot: {newRoot: '$filesFolders'}}
])
```